# Include php en bootstrap me lleva al top

Tags: php, bootstrap

como dice el titulo, al agregar un include en una plantilla de bootstrap y pulsar el boton "calcular" me lleva de nuevo al top de la pagina.

El include es una calculadora y los codigos que fallan pueden ser:

```
<section id="calcular">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2>Calculadora</h2>
                    <hr>
<?php include 'calculator.php'?>
                </div>

            </div>
```

y el form es:

```
    <form method="post">
    <div class="calculator_div">
        <div>
<input type="radio" value="metric" name="system" <?php if($_SESSION['bmi_calc_system']!='' and $_SESSION['bmi_calc_system']=='metric') ;?> onclick="changeSystem('metric');"> Metrico &nbsp;
<input type="radio" value="english" name="system" <?php if($_SESSION['bmi_calc_system']=="" or $_SESSION['bmi_calc_system']=='english') ;?> onclick="changeSystem('english');"> Ingles


</div>
        <div><label>Tu peso:</label>
            <span id="englishWeight" style="display:<?php echo ($_SESSION['bmi_calc_system']=='' or $_SESSION['bmi_calc_system']=='english')?'block':'none'?>;"><input type="text" name="weight_en" size="6" value="<?php echo !empty($_SESSION['bmi_calc_weight_en'])?$_SESSION['bmi_calc_weight_en']:""?>"> lbs</span>
            <span id="metricWeight" style="display:<?php echo (($_SESSION['bmi_calc_system']=="" or $_SESSION['bmi_calc_system']=='english'))?'none':'block'?>;"><input type="text" name="weight_met" size="6" value="<?php echo !empty($_SESSION['bmi_calc_weight_met'])?$_SESSION['bmi_calc_weight_met']:""?>"> kg</span>
        </div>   
        <div><label>Tu altura:</label>
            <span id="englishHeight" style="display:<?php echo (($_SESSION['bmi_calc_system']=='' or $_SESSION['bmi_calc_system']=='english'))?'block':'none'?>;"><input type="text" size="6" name="height_ft_en" value="<?php echo !empty($_SESSION['bmi_calc_height_ft_en'])?$_SESSION['bmi_calc_height_ft_en']:""?>"> ft
            &nbsp; <input type="text" size="6" name="height_in_en" value="<?php echo ($_SESSION['bmi_calc_height_in_en']!='')?$_SESSION['bmi_calc_height_in_en']:""?>"> in</span>
            <span id="metricHeight" style="display:<?php echo ($_SESSION['bmi_calc_system']=='' or $_SESSION['bmi_calc_system']=='english')?'none':'block'?>;">
            <input type="text" name="height_met" size="6" value="<?php echo ($_SESSION['bmi_calc_height_met']!='')?$_SESSION['bmi_calc_height_met']:""?>"> cm
            </span>
        </div>
        <div align="center">
            <input type="hidden" name="calculator_ok" value="ok">
<br><br>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Calcular !!!</button>

        </div>

    </div>    
    </form>
```

si me falta agregar algun dato diganme, y gracias por tomarse el tiempo de ayudar

Comment: Das muy pocos datos y así no sabemos que puede ser. Lo único que puedo adelantarte es que al utilizar type=submit en el botón, por defecto intentará enviar el formulario en el cual se encuentra el botón. De ahí que te mande al top. Prueba a cambiar a type button y no te ocurrirá.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en que estás clickeando en el botón calcular, submiteando el formuladio, como no especificaste el atributo `action` está redirigiendo enviando la información a la misma página.

Por ende, no te está llevando al top, te está recargando la página. Si querés evitar este problema podrías poner un botón de la siguiente manera

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Calcular !!!</button>
```

Declarando el `type="button"` no va a realizar un submit del formulario cuando sea clickeado, por ende no vas a enviar la información que necesitas para hacer el cálculo. Creo que una solución con `javascript` te va a ser más conveniente si querés eliminar el scroll al top automático.

Comment: ya probe eso, y al modificarlo como tu dices, no funciona, de la otra manera si me da el resultado pero recarga la pagina y me lleva al top

Comment: Claro, porque no estás enviando la información. Yo solo te puse el motivo de porque te está llevando al principio de la página. Si querés que se recargue y scrollee directamente a donde querés tendrías que abrir otro tópico

Comment: Ahí edité la respuesta agregando un comentario con respecto a lo que decías, espero que te sirva de ayuda. Saludos!

Comment: gracias, pero lo solucione declarando el action y que me lleve a la parte del html donde mostraba el resultado con un ancla #resultado y quedo perfecto, de todos modos voy a averiguar lo que dices de javascript por si queda mejor